# twilio get message details (method not allowed )

Tags: javascript, twilio

```
 url = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/'+ACCOUNT_SID+'/SMS/Messages/'+Sid+'.json';

 var payLoadData = {
          'SMSMessageSid' : Sid
        };
 var options =
      {
        method : "GET",
        payload : payLoadData,
        headers : {
          'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(ACCOUNT_SID + ':' + ACCOUNT_TOKEN)
        }
      };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

Why by using this google_script gives a Method_Not_Allowed

```
Request failed for https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/XXXXXXXXXXXXX/SMS/Messages/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.json returned code 405. Server response: {"status":405,"message":"Method not allowed","code":20004,"more_info":"http:\/\/www.twilio.com\/docs\/errors\/20004"} (line 374, file "MakePhoneCall")
```

As we can see, https://www.twilio.com/user/account/developer-tools/api-explorer#GET/2010-04-01/Accounts/[AccountSid]/SMS/Messages/[SMSMessageSid].[format]

it's constructed according to this api ref

Answer (score 1):

It seems that payload shouldn't be used while using GET method, hence using params would do the trick.

Still, the same method works when getting details of call, but not with message, interesting :)